# Count distinct with multiple columns JPA2 specifications

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, exception

I'm trying to find some results from my Oracle database and because of the data model, I have repeated data which I don't want to be shown.

In order to do this, I thought using DISTINCT in my CriteriaQuery should do the trick. But here I encountered the problem:

The distinct has to be made on 2 columns and this makes the code to throw the following exception: "ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments".

After some google search, found that using this things: || to separate the columns works, but I don't have a single clue to do this either.

So:

The correct way to distinct my data is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 FROM ...
```

But Hibernate is building it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT( DISTINCT column1, column2) FROM
```

The latter query is the one that throws the exception. Is there a way to tell Hibernate to do the first of the two queries?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The code involved is this:

```
return new Specification<ProfilingInstructionAccessEntity>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ProfilingInstructionAccessEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            List<FilterDTO> activeFilters = filtersService.findAllActive();

            filters.forEach((k, v) -> {
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(v)) {
                    SpecificationHelperEnum helperEnum = SpecificationHelperEnum.getByKey(k);
                    SpecFilter filter = (SpecFilter) appContext.getBean(helperEnum.getFilter());
  //                        query.select(root.get("concated")).distinct(true); <-- This line is what I tried. Also tried this: query.distinct(true);
                    Predicate predicate = filter.createSmartPredicate(root, cb, v, helperEnum.getFilterId(), activeFilters);

                    predicates.add(predicate);
                }
            });
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    };

@Override
public Predicate createSmartPredicate(Root<ProfilingInstructionAccessEntity> root, CriteriaBuilder cb, String value, Integer filterId, List<FilterDTO> activeFilters) {
    List<AssetDTO> assets = service.findBySpec("origin", value);
    List<Predicate> assetPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Join<Object, Object> aux = root.join(SearchPathEnum.ACCESS.getPath()).join(SearchPathEnum.ACCESS_FILTERS.getPath());
    for (AssetDTO assetDTO : assets) {
        List<Predicate> filterPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FilterDTO filterDTO : activeFilters) {
            filterPredicates.add(buildPredicate(assetDTO, filterDTO.getMappedValue(), aux, cb));
        }
        assetPredicates.add(cb.or(filterPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[filterPredicates.size()])));
    }
    return cb.or(assetPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[assetPredicates.size()]));
}

private Predicate buildPredicate(AssetDTO assetDTO, String mappedValue, Join<Object, Object> aux, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Predicate filterCode = cb.equal(aux.get(SearchPathEnum.FILTER.getPath()).get(SearchPathEnum.MAPPED_VALUE.getPath()), mappedValue);
    String value = (String) ReflectionComponent.invokeByReflection(assetDTO, "get" + StringUtils.capitalize(mappedValue), null);
    Predicate filterValue = cb.like(aux.get(SearchPathEnum.FILTER_VALUE.getPath()), "%" + value.trim() + "%");
    return cb.and(filterCode, filterValue);
}
```

It's a bit complex but in the end it is something like a 'smart' search. I have like 20 filters and any single one of them trigger the search by the others.

If more information is needed please feel free to ask for it. Thanks!

Comment: what about using native query? can you please show us your code?

Comment: Sorry to reopen this issue after so much time, but we encountered the same issue. Do you remember how you fixed it ?

Answer (score 1):

`count(distinct column1, column2)` is invalid.

That would, actually, be

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct column1, column2 from some_table);
```

I don't know *hibernate*, but - maybe code posted above rings your bell :)

Comment: The problem is that Hibernate does that distinct count thing on its own and I can't change that (or at least, I don't know how)

Answer (score 1):

Register new function in Dialect:

```
registerFunction("count_distinct", new SQLFunctionTemplate(IntegerType.INSTANCE, "count(distinct ?1)"));
```

And concatenate:

```
select count_distinct(column1 || column2) from some_table
```